# How to set node version to 16.x for ruby:3.0.1-alpine3.13 image in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

The following is the `Dockerfile` I have set up for one of my applications:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.1-alpine3.13

ENV APP_PATH /var/app
ENV BUNDLE_VERSION 2.2.17
ENV RAILS_PORT 3000
ENV LAUNCHY_DRY_RUN true
ENV BROWSER /dev/null

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

# install dependencies for M1 Macs
RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl py-pip python2 python3

# install dependencies for application
RUN apk -U add --no-cache \
make \
gcc \
build-base \
git \
postgresql-dev \
postgresql-client \
libxml2-dev \
libxslt-dev \
nodejs \
npm \
yarn \
tzdata \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
&& mkdir -p $APP_PATH


RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLE_VERSION"

# navigate to app directory
WORKDIR $APP_PATH

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN bundle check || bundle install --jobs=8
RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . .

EXPOSE $RAILS_PORT
```

This by default sets the node version to `14.17.4`. This used to work when I had set the node engine value in package.json to `14.x`, but since I have changed the node engine value to `16.x` I'm getting this error when I'm trying to build a container with this Dockerfile.

I have searched and tried various approaches to set the node version in Dockerfile using nvm, n, etc, but to no avail.

Is there an easy way to set and change this node version?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ```#15 1.335 yarn install v1.22.10                                                                                                                                             
#15 1.749 [1/5] Validating package.json...                                                                                                                                  
#15 1.757 error @: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "16.x". Got "14.17.4"                                                               
#15 1.776 error Found incompatible module.```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For installing Node.js 16.x on Alpine 3.14, install the `nodejs-current` package:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.14/community/x86_64/nodejs-current

Simply replace `nodejs` with `nodejs-current` in your package list.
The current `nodejs-current` version is 16.6.0-r0.